# Swift iOS: default font values differs

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uikit, uilabel

### According to the Apple's documentation:

- UITextField

  > The default font is a 12-point Helvetica plain font [[1]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619604-font)
- UITextView

  > This property applies to the entire text string. The default font is a 
  >   17-point Helvetica plain font [[2]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextview/1618600-font?language=objc)
- UILabel:

  > The default value for this property is the system font at a size of 17
  >   points (using the systemFont(ofSize:) class method of UIFont) [[3]](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uilabel/1620532-font)

---

### - But according to my debug output:

> [image]

---

**Question:** What is the reason my debug output differs (font and sizes) from Apple's documentation?

**Implementation details:** I don't use IB, my project is 100% programatically. The UITextField, UITextView, and UILabel are specified in a custom UITableViewCell. I have never touched, queried, or changed the value of any font properties directly and indirectly (as I know of).

Comment: Check this one http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208849/is-there-a-user-font-for-san-francisco-in-el-capitan

Comment: Seems like the documentation for `UITextField` and `UITextView` is outdated.